# Why I always need a C compiler environment when build OCaml and OCaml codes?

Tags: compilation, ocaml

This is a a question in my head for some years, I am using OCaml under windows, when I build each OCaml distribution version, I need a C compiler, either MSVC or MingGW, and I have to do it under Cygwin.

When I have my OCaml in hand, and when I need to compile my codes, I also need the c linker that I used for compiling my OCaml..for me it's very strange. Why OCaml can't auto bootstrap with an elder version of OCaml instead of some C compiler?

Answer (score 5):

The OCaml toolchain relies on external tools to assemble and link binaries. The latter is probably more important than assembler, as assemblers are more or less stable. But linkers are usually deeply integrated with an operating system and differ each version. Bundling them will increase support burden and make OCaml programs less portable and the whole OCaml distribution more fragile. So, depending on assembler/linker abstraction is sort of a sweet point, that minimizes dependencies and support burden and maximizes portability.

Other languages, usually, follow the same approach. Even those that depend on LLVM, as LLVM actually uses the GNU toolchain linker underneath the hood.

For building OCaml itself, the C compiler is absolutely necessary. The OCaml itself is not written entirely in OCaml. In fact, OCaml runtime is written in pure C, e.g., garbage collector. Also, many functions, especially that define system interface (e.g., Unix) are also written in C. The `sloccount` tool gives us a rough estimate, that 15% of OCaml source code (45,000 LOC) is written in C.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, got it understand. I got this question since I learnt Rust compiler is initially written in OCaml and then auto-bootstrapped later.

Answer (score 0):

The OCaml bytecode interpreter is written in C - see the description in the OCaml README [here](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml#overview).

Comment: It's about bootstrap, but I still need the c linker in the environement when I have the complete built ocaml to compile my ml files, why?

Answer (score 0):

> ivg's answer says it all, but I'll just give a quick tip for Windows 10 users.

I always recommend that Windows 10 users use [Ubuntu on Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). You'll then have access to a fully-fledged Unix environment instead of Cygwin, which include (among other things) a built-in C tool chain.

I'd only use Windows to develop if I intend to release on Windows, which I rarely do. Even then, I'd prefer to use a cross-compiler and use Windows only for testing.

Comment: There's problem with bash on windows, if you tape ocamlc, it will only search for ocamlc, never ocamlc.exe, so I can't build ocaml and libs with bash on windows

Comment: Sure. If you want to compile using Bash on Windows but execute on Windows, you'll need a cross-compiler.

Comment: Well, only my sub-project (a background service) uses OCaml and the main project is compiled with MSVC..so when I came to crosscompiler, which is supposed to be MinGW, I think there will be a problem to incorporate the two..